# Java run command line which contains spaces

Tags: java, command-line, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to run a .bat file from my Java app. I've tried all the methods I could find, but none seems to work.

The problem is that the path to the .bat file containing spaces.

I'm using [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/how-to-execute-command-prompt-command-view-output-java/) method now so I can see the results in my Eclipse console

My actual code is:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
String processString = "cmd /c \"" + homeFolder.getAbsolutePath() + SETUP_FILE + "\" \"" + homeFolder.getAbsolutePath() + "\"";
    try {
        Process proc = rt.exec(processString);
    ...
    }
```

I've tried with escaping the quotes, without escaping quotes, separating the string into `String[]` and placing each space separated command its own cell:

```
{ "cmd", "/c", \"" + homeFolder.getAbsolutePath() + SETUP_FILE + "\" ... };
```

Again, with and without escaping the quotes: nothing works.

I also tried hard-coding the paths to both the array and the string. Same results every time.

```
homeFolder = C:\Users\La bla bla\workspace\ToolMaker\bin\
SETUP_FILE = setup.bat
```

The whole command is this:

```
cmd /c "C:\Users\La bla bla\workspace\ToolMaker\bin\setup.bat" "C:\Users\La bla bla\workspace\ToolMaker\bin"
```

Again, with or without quotes, same output:

```
Output: 
Error: 'C:\Users\La' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

Obviously I'm running on Windows (7, 64 bit professional). Java 7

I saw a few people said they had this issues before, but I couldn't find an answer on how to get around that.

Comment: have you tried to encode space character?

Comment: I've tried to encode the entire string using UTF-8. not sure if that's what u mean

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the version of [`Runtime.exec(String[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5b%5d%29) that takes a `String[]`:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
String[] processCommand = { "cmd", "/c", path };

try
{
    Process proc = rt.exec(processCommand);
    // ...
}
```

This works for me (Win7):

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
String[] processCommand = { "cmd", "/c", "c:" + File.separatorChar + "dir with spaces" + File.separatorChar + "test.bat" };

System.out.println("xPATH: " + processCommand[2]);

Process p = rt.exec(processCommand);
// output of the command is as expected
```

This also works if I use `\` explicitly:

```
String[] processCommand = { "cmd", "/c", "c:\\dir with spaces\\test.bat" };
```

Comment: Really, I just did this test without issue `Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd", "/c", "dir", "C:/Program Files (x86)"});`

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and for some reason it worked... though, if i'm adding "runas", "/user:administrator" ,.. to the array, it no longer works. and I need to run the batch as an administrator

Comment: Never mind. I got the order wrong.. though it still asks me for a password... obviously.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but I was using the `start` parameter, so it might not be "exactly" the same problem.

`cmd` doesn't like extended directory names (I don't know why personally, I just know it doesn't).  It will want the "shortened" (8.2) names instead

That means `wallpaper.jpg` needs to become `WALLPA~1.JPG`

Here, you run into a problem.  What happens if you have a number of `wallpaper*.*` files, which one do you want??

Now, to get this to work under windows properly, you're going to have to get down to the native level.

There's a Windows function called `GetShortPathName` (and variants of) which basically given a "long name" (path and file name) will generate the "short name" for you.

Comment: When I copy and paste the whole command into cmd, it works.. I'll look into this function.