# How to open any file with a directory with spaces in cmd?

Tags: java, excel, cmd, runtime

I am doing a program in Java and for open the history stored in an Excel file, I open my file using cmd. I use this instruction.

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c   start  P:\\ges of cam\\Results" + LocalDate.now().getMonthValue() + "-" + LocalDate.now().getYear() + ".csv");`

As you imagine, when I click the button associated to this instruction, it does not open, I know why it is.
The problem is that a directory have spaces and cmd do not find it, but
I am interested in my history continues in this folder without changing the name of the folder. Is there any solution for that?

I am working in Windows 7 and Windows 10 computers.

Comment: You can also supply an argument list as an array of strings using [`Runtime.exec(String[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821277/java-run-command-line-which-contains-spaces

Comment: First of all: dont use getRuntime().exec(). Read about using the ProcessBuilder API instead.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use double quotes for the part of the path which includes spaces. 
In order for java not interpret the double quotes as an end of the string you will also need to escape them.

i.e. `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c   start  P:\\\"ges of cam\"\\Results" + LocalDate.now().getMonthValue() + "-" + LocalDate.now().getYear() + ".csv");`

Comment: Probably the best option would be to add double quotes at the start and end of the whole path, not just around parts containing spaces.

Comment: It worked fine. Nice tip, I read something about but when I tried I got some errors